# PayPal Adaptive Payments API, REST API or Classic API ??? which one to use?

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments

I am struggling for the last 3 days to understand how to make a chained payment with paypal API. I am using Xampp on XP and PHP version is 5.3.1. cURL and openssl is enabled.

My question is that I want to implement chained payment but there are so many things I dont know which one to use, Adaptive payment SDK, REST API or Classic API??? I need a simple answer where to start, which one to use and is there any special way to install those SDKs in xampp 1.7 on XP. I get the below error too.

`Fatal error: Class 'PayPal\Types\AP\Receiver' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\papp\samples\PayReceipt.php on line 40`

seems like path issue and I dont know where to place paypal folder.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: any ideas on this. I am also getting this kind of error :|

Comment: anyone resolved this issue? :|